# Assigning function output to many variables: good or bad practice

Tags: python, function, design-patterns, variable-assignment, assign

Is it an unusual design pattern to assign output of function to many variables? Imagine each variable below representing complex data, such as nested dictionaries.

```
def step_1():
    a = ...
    ...
    i = ...

    return a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i

def step_2(a, b, c, d, e, f):
    ...
    return j
    
def step_3(g, h, i, j):
    ...
    return k


a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i = step_1()
j = step_2(a, b, c, d, e, f)
k = step_3(g, h, i, j)
# do something with k
```

Somehow it feels odd doing things like

`a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i = step_1()` or

`return a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i` or

`j = step_2(a, b, c, d, e, f)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're returning `a,b,c,...,i`, that's a bit excessive, though in general this isn't (necessarily) a poor design choice. In reality, this is the product of two Python features:

- From the `return` statement, Python is interpreting/ treating the return type as a tuple that, syntactically, has been expanded, rather than treating it as the union of however many variables individually. That is, you could equivalently define a tuple `tuple = (a,...,i)` and return that.
- Then again when you assign the `a, ..., i = step1()`, you're again expanding this tuple.

What you might consider is treating it as a tuple, ie, a single object, rather than 9 individual items, since it doesn't seem that you need all of them at once. This might be better for code style, etc.

Since you make the distinction that these `a,...,i` are "complex data" items, though you have given little about your particular case, it's probably best to split up this functionality to make its scope as clear, tight, and therefore manageable as possible. If I was working with you, I'd probably implore you to do so before I'd write any unit tests for it.

Comment: Indeed, each letter variable is complex (e.g. nested dict of dicts) and represent something distinct. Bundling all in a tuple only adds a level of nestedness. But could work, unpacking tuple inside the scope of individual functions. Thanks for answer.

Comment: From personal experience this helps up until the complexity is medicore but once the complexity increases you will want some thing to have associated with it, until when can you go on with the indexes and remember it. Dictionary is good choice since you can add additional elements and also its easy to call as the keys are unique and the game changing aspect is the readability as well as the power to update a instance according to your need without scratching your head.

Comment: @ArunbhYashaswi I'd argue that, if you were to reach such a point, your proposal is a hack/ kicking the can down the road for a much larger issue with the codebase --- if you need one function to do 20 things, you've a.s. opened yourself up to a lot of easy mistakes. Note that dictionaries are significantly more expensive than tuples; it's more performant to keep track of whatever extra add-on's in a tighter scope whenever possible. There are much better solutions.

Comment: @mjachi are you saying to break down step_1 into several functions referenced in main scope? Yes, also a solution. No need to be overly brief in main at the cost of readability?

Comment: There shall be some sort of relationship between main scope complexity and number of variables. Low number of variables = short main, high number of vars = longer main, utra high number of vars = added layer of nestedness?

Comment: @aeiou I don't know what your use case is, but yes... probably best to break that up if you can. In the long term, it's more important that you understand how the codebase works/ precisely how things fit together over getting the "front" end of it in as few lines as possible. If you include something like `argparse`, it's basically going to get torn up anyways.

Comment: @aeiou For your 2nd comment, try to move your `if __name__ == "__main__"` bit towards the "fewest number of actions possible"/ "delegates everything to abstractions," in essence.

Answer (score 2):

Generally in such cases a seperate dictionary is maintained with all the outputs being stored it has many issue. you can save it as json easily or even you can pass required fields from it manually but this makes the redability of the code much more.

For example here `final_output = {"a":a,'b':b,'c':c}`

and returning this `final_output` instead. This actually I use it in for business purposes.